# Handlebars in Meteor calls callback for each Helper?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

When you create a handlebars template with this content:

```
<template name="list">
  {{#if array}}
    <ul>
      {{#each array}}
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
    No items.
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

and a Template callback.

```
Template.list.array = function() {
  // Some queries here + logic to build your array.
};
```

your Template callback will be called twice.. for the **if** Helper and **each** Helper.
isn't it a performance issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my answer? (unaccepted)

Comment: Sorry, I got it! Thank's for your answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite it as:

```
<template name="list">
  {{#with array}}
    <ul>
      {{#each .}}
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
    No items.
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: Cool, so easy! Thanks Xyand.

Comment: the last {{/if}} should be {{/with}} I think.